# Setting Default and MinDate value of Extjs Datepicker dynamically

Tags: extjs

> I have a datepicker in an Extjs window . The min date and default
>   date should come from an store DateSTORE for instance. How can i
>   do this ? This is my code.

```
     {
                                                  xtype:'datefield',  
                                                  margin: '20 20 0 10',
                                                  labelAlign: 'right',
                                                  labelWidth: 140,
                                                  width: 350,
                                                  itemId:'beginningDate',
                                                  fieldLabel: "Beginning Date", 
                                                   minDate:function(){

                                                  waitForStoreLoading([Ext.StoreManager.lookup('DateSTORE').load()], function () {
                                                      debugger

                                                      var dateStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('DateSTORE').data.items[0].data.ProductionMonth;
                                                      return jsDate = new Date(parseInt(dateStore.substr(6)));
                                                      var monthProduction = DateSTORE.data.items[0].data.ProductionMonthString
                                                      Ext.apply(Ext.getCmp('Window').down('#beginningDate'), {minDate:jsDate});
                                                      Ext.getCmp('Window').down('#beginningDate').getView.refresh();
                                                  });
                                                  }(),
```

But the store is being undefined. tried setting the date on click of the button which opens this particular 'window' . But its not happening either . Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set min value on store's load event

//datefield

```
{
    xtype:'datefield',  
    margin: '20 20 0 10',
    labelAlign: 'right',
    labelWidth: 140,
    width: 350,
    itemId:'beginningDate',
    fieldLabel: "Beginning Date",
    id:"beginningDate"
}
```

//store

```
{
    listeners:{
        load:funciton(store, records){
            var str = records[0].get("ProductionMonth");
            var datefield = Ext.getCmp("beginningDate");
            datefield.setMinValue(str);
    }    
}
```